# "Using" is not solving the "hides virtual function" warning

Tags: overloading, c++builder, using, c++builder-xe7

I have been googling high and low and can't find a solution that will remove the warning, even when I use the `using` directive.

```
class TShowException_Form : public TForm {

    __published: // IDE-managed Components
        TButton *Send_Button;
        TButton *Cancel_Button;
        TLabel  *Message_Label;

    private:    // User declarations
        using TCustomForm::ShowModal;
        //using TForm::ShowModal;

    public:     // User declarations
            __fastcall TShowException_Form(TComponent* Owner);
        int __fastcall ShowModal(System::Sysutils::Exception *E);
};
```

I want to hide the original `virtual int __fastcall ShowModal(void)` and expose a new one taking an Exception parameter.

But it still complaints on "hides virtual function":

```
[bcc32 Warning] TShowExceptionForm.h(32): '_fastcall TShowException_Form::ShowModal(Exception *)' hides virtual function '_fastcall TCustomForm::ShowModal()'
```

I have also tried `using TForm::ShowModal;` but with the same result.
Any ideas of how to solve this warning?

---

**EDIT**
I found out that it works perfectly well if I override the `show()` method instead:

```
class TShowException_Form : public TForm {

    __published: // IDE-managed Components
        TButton *Send_Button;
        TButton *Cancel_Button;
        TLabel  *Message_Label;

    private:    // User declarations
        using TForm::ShowModal;
        using TForm::Show;

    public:     // User declarations
            __fastcall TShowException_Form(TComponent* Owner);
        int __fastcall Show(System::Sysutils::Exception *E);
};
```

So why isn't it working with `ShowModal()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bcc32 is, in many respects, not very compliant with the C++ standard. Whenever I find myself asking, "Why does this technique that I think should work in C++ not work in bcc32?", I usually assume it's yet another compiler bug.

The fact that `Show` works while `ShowModal` doesn't is interesting. Looking at Vcl.Forms.hpp shows the difference: `Show` is defined with `HIDESBASE` (a macro that expands to [`__declspec(hidesbase)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declspec%28hidesbase%29)).

Adding HIDESBASE to your ShowModal should work as well. You may also have to declare a virtual destructor, if you don't already have one, due to bcc32 compiler weirdness.

```
virtual __Fastcall ~TShowException_Form() {}
```

Comment: The HIDEBASE did the trick. Yes, i'm also used to the C++Builder quirks, but this was a new one for me...

Comment: Yes, `HIDESBASE` is the correct answer when you want to **hide and overload** a base class virtual method and not **override** it.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare overloaded version as `virtual` too:

```
virtual int __fastcall ShowModal(System::SysUtils::Exception * E);
```

Does not know if C++Builder supports C++11, but if it does, try also to `delete` overload which you want to hide:

```
virtual int __fastcall ShowModal() = delete;
```

instead of placing it into private section.

Comment: virtual doesn't help, but I found out that if I declare the `ShowModal` body in the class definition, it works, but not If I place it in the .cpp file. Bcc32 in XE7 doesn't have the full C++11 implemented, so delete didn't work.

Comment: C++Builder's 64-bit compiler for Windows (introduced in XE2) supports C++11. C++Builder just recently gained a [new 32-bit C++11 compiler for Windows](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/What%27s_New#New_Clang-enhanced_C.2B.2B_Compiler_for_32-bit_Windows) in C++Builder 10 Seattle (the 32-bit OSX compiler does not support C++11 yet, AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning because what you are trying to do happens very often by mistake and is a serious and very hard to find bug if it is done by mistake. *Maybe* you should use a different name.

Comment: ...and that is why I'm using the `using TForm::ShowModal;` statement to tell the compiler that this is what I want.